# SQLite tables not populating from multiple seeds files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, sqlite

My database is not populating when I run `$ rake db:seed`, and does not raise any errors, either.

Here's a portion of my seeds file:

```
require 'date'

holidays_array = []
holidays = File.open('holidays_seeds.txt')
holidays.each("],"=$/) do |holiday|
  holidays_array << holiday.split(",").strip
end
holidays.close

holidays_array.each do |name, link_url, date|
  Holiday.create!( 
    name: name, 
    link_url: link_url, 
    date: date)
end

...
```

Here's the format of 'holidays_seeds.txt':

```
# January
[
  "New Year's Day", 
  "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Year%27s_Day", 
  "#{DateTime.new(Date.today.year, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)}"
],
[
  "Martin Luther King Jr. Day",
  "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin_Luther_King,_Jr._Day",
  'varies'
],
...
```

And here's my Holiday model:

```
class Holiday < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :countries
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

In `$ rails dbconsole`, when I `SELECT * FROM holidays;`, it gives me nothing. `PRAGMA table_info(holidays);` shows column headings.

I am probably overlooking something obvious. Can you tell me what that might be?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We don't really care whether you're new to Ruby/Rails or experienced, we just expect thought-out questions and for you to do your homework before asking. If you do those things you'll be rewarded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding the filepath to `File.open('db/seeds/holidays_seeds.txt')` populated the database.